# How can I use directly function in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In this code, I would like to show data with directly using function `_renderMovies`
not like

```
{movies? this._renderMovies(): 'Loading!' }
```

cuz I don't want to show Loadings

Do you guys have an idea of how can I use directly function _renderMovies?

*My code* :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L_MovieList from './L_MovieList';
import L_Ranking from './L_Ranking';
import './L_BoxOffice.css';
class L_BoxOffice extends Component {
  state ={

  }
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._renderMovies = this._renderMovies.bind(this);
  }
componentDidMount(){
    this._getMovies();
}
_renderMovies=()=>{
  const movies= this.state.movies.map((movie)=>{
    console.log(movie)
      return  <L_Ranking
      title={movie.title_english}
      key={movie.id}
      genres={movie.genres}
      />
  })
  return movies
}
_getMovies = async()=>{
 const movies = await this._callApi() 
 this.setState({
   //movies : movies
   movies 
 })
}
  _callApi=()=>{
    return   fetch('https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count')
    .then(potato=> potato.json()) 
    .then(json=> json.data.movies)
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
  render() {
      const{movies}=this.state;
    return (
      <div>

      <div className={movies ? "L_BoxOffice" : "L_BoxOffice--loading"}>
      <div className="L_Ranking_title">RANKING</div>
{movies? this._renderMovies(): 'Loading!' }
      </div>
        Box office page
        <L_MovieList/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default L_BoxOffice;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set `movies` to be an empty array by default in the state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { movies: [] }
  this._renderMovies = this._renderMovies.bind(this);
}
```

After that just render the movies:

```
<div className="L_Ranking_title">RANKING</div>
  {this._renderMovies()}
</div>
```

Having an empty array as a default value, will remove the ternary operator usage and `.map` will always work, because by default the `movies` will be iterable.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! you helped me! Can I ask one more question? after fixed it, the data comes out late..around 2sec. I want to show date right when open the page. Is that because I put the function in componentDidMount()?.. why _renderMovies returns so late?

Comment: In short: it's fine that you call it in `componentDidMount()`. It won't have too improvement if you call it in the constructor or any other lifecycle method. Please read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/where-to-integrate-api-calls-in-reactjs-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-710085dc05c3). It depends to your app architecture. You can create a HOC that will be responsible for data fetching, but keep in mind that there will be always a resource loading time, because of the API server response time.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `{movies? this._renderMovies(): 'Loading!' }` with `_this.renderMovies()`

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function

like you can directly call any function like this

```
_renderMovies = ()=>{
 if(true){

  }else{
   return 'loading...' //just an example
   }
}

render(){
  {this._renderMovies()}
}
```